# How do you rotate a React-Icon?

Tags: reactjs

I have looked at different solutions on SO, but nothing has worked so far, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation. I have done things like:

in my Icon context provider:

```
style:{transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]}
```

as well as inserting the style directly into the icon tag like:

```
<BiCard style = {{transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]}}>
```

But none of this seems to be working. I have tried rotateX and rotateY as well. Is there some newer way to do this?

Comment: do you have a codepen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should pass a string to your `transform` property not an array.

If you pass as below it should work as expected:

```
<BiCard style = {{transform: 'rotate(90deg)' }} />
```